# How to enable Auto-Login for Teamcity Tray Notifier

Tags: teamcity, autologin

I am using the [TeamCity Tray Notifier for Windows](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Windows+Tray+Notifier).

I found the option to enable "start with windows".

But after restarting windows it always requires me to log in again manually.

Is there a way to get it to automatically log in or just "stay logged in" when restarting it?